# Is there a fortran solver able to solve the following eigenvalue?

Tags: fortran, eigenvalue

**A** is an N by N matrix. **I** is the unit matrix of (N-2) by (N-2). B is another N by N matrix which is defined as

```
    B=[I 0 0;
       0 0 0;
       0 0 0]
```

. **x** is an array with N elements. How can I solve the eigenvalue of the following form
**A** **x**=c**B** **x**, where c is the eigenvalue,
by using an eigenvalue solver?

Comment: Also google for [Generalized Eigenvalue Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the [Lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) library, which offers solutions for eigenvalues problems of generalized matrices. Depending on your data type and matrix type you will need to use different subroutines.
Have a look [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d4/d7a/group__eigen_g_e.html) on this regard. Also have a look [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node24.html) for the nomenclature used as type of matrix.

Finally, sometime ago I wrote [this module](https://github.com/b-fg/LAPACK_helper) to give an implementation example of a few Lapack functionalities, including eigenvalue problems. The one you can find there is for a single value generalized matrix ([`sgeev`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d3/dfb/group__real_g_eeigen_ga104525b749278774f7b7f57195aa6798.html#ga104525b749278774f7b7f57195aa6798)).